# How to automatically grow width of NSTextField as per content but only until certain width?

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield, xcode-storyboard

I have a NSTextField. I want it to grow in width and height. However the NSTextField is inside a view. I don't want the text field's width grow beyond 60% of its super view. Once the width has reached 60% width of superview I want the text field to increase in height. Is there anyway I can achieve this using storyboards? Basically the text field is basically a subview of NSTableCellView. So I want the text field to adjust it's height whenever the table view is resized.